# Nest.js Bull not running jobs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

Im trying to get Bull to run some jobs and have a set-up running but I get a time out error

```
ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20). Refer to "maxRetriesPerRequest" option for details.
```

So I have set up the app.module

```js
BullModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        redis: {
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 6379,
        },
        prefix: 'bull-queue',
        maxRetriesPerRequest: 3,
        defaultJobOptions: {
          attempts: 3,
          removeOnComplete: false,
          backoff: {
            type: 'exponential',
            delay: 1000,
          },
        },
      }),
    }),
```

Then I have a consumer set up

```js
import { Job } from 'bull';
import { Process, Processor } from '@nestjs/bull';

@Processor('code')
export class CodeConsumer {
  @Process('code-job')
  handleTranscode(job: Job) {
    console.log('Start audio compress into mp3...');
    console.log(job.data);
    console.log('completed!!');
  }
}
```

My asset code module registers the Queue

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AssetCodesService } from './asset-codes.service';
import { AssetCodesController } from './asset-codes.controller';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AssetCode } from './entities/asset-code.entity';
import { BullModule } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { CodeConsumer } from './consumers/qrcode.consumer';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([AssetCode]),
    BullModule.registerQueueAsync({
      name: 'code',
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AssetCodesController],
  providers: [AssetCodesService, CodeConsumer],
})
export class AssetCodesModule {}
```

and finally my controller injects the queue and uses it to create the job

```js
constructor(
    private readonly assetCodesService: AssetCodesService,
    @InjectQueue('code') private codeQueue: Queue,
  ) {}

@Post('create')
  async startJob() {
    console.log(this.codeQueue.client.status);
    await this.codeQueue.add('code-job', {
      foo: 'bar',
    });
  }
```

The status log in the controller function gives me a message of 'reconnecting'

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is possibly because your redis is not initialized on your local machine. In the event that you are using a redis in the cloud, remember that you should not enter the entire path of the redis host, that is: you should color only the url, without the "redis://" and without the port at the end. You only put the host, as well as the port and password in other variables.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).